# problema con el carrusel , con dropdown y web responsive con Bootstrap5

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive, carrusel, dropdown

necesito ayuda ya que me encuentro creando una web html con bootstrap y js para la universidad, y tengo los siguientes problemas:

1.En la ventana "**Home**", me piden un carrusel que cambie la imagen automáticamente, hice que cambie de forma automática pero ahora al presionar las flechas para cambiar manualmente, no hace nada.

2.En la ventana "**About-we**", puse un navbar (menú) que es el mismo de la ventana "**Home**", el cual tiene una opción dropdown que en la ventana "**Home**" funciona pero en la ventana "**About-we**" no.

3.Me piden que mi web sea responsive, la ventana "**Home**" cumple con esto pero la ventana "**About-we**" no, y no se el porque.

Eso sería todo, si es que me pueden ayudar se los agradecería mucho, aqui les dejo un link de drive para que puedan descargar los archivos de la web:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/100-VJYjZeOfDg0sOzP4jH0K2xwTsKt18?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- El problema es que tus `data-bs-target` tienen `#carouselExampleCaptions` cuando debiera ser `#carouselExampleAutoplaying` es decir la ID de tu carousel

2.- Basta con agregar la libreria de bootstrap que si agregaste en home pero no en about_we.html la cual es `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

3.- Si la veo de forma responsiva, quizás es algún problema con tu cache puedes intentar si estas en windows en tu navegador y en esa pagina con ctrl+f5 el cual hace un hard refresh borrando todo el cache de esa pagina

Comment: Toda la razón, ahí lo solucioné, muchisimas gracias!